# Jquery Datatable Server Side Pagination With External Search field

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable, pagination

I have a Jquery Datatable which displays some data and it has an external search field.I am trying to implement Server side pagination with the help of Jquery Datatable plugin.But the problem is,it has an external search field,in which user can select a date(basically month and year) and search for the records.So, every time user opt for a search the datatable need to be refreshed.Can anyone help me on this.

**Datatable**

```
var LeaveDetailsTable = $('#LvReprtTable').DataTable({
    "pageLength": 5,
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,"searching": false,"bLengthChange": false,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "GetLeaveDetails",
        "type": "POST",
        "datatype": "json",
        "data": function (d) {
            d.EmpId = empId;
            d.UserType = userType;
            d.Month = "1";
            d.year = "2017";
        }
    },
    "columns": [
            { "data": "_fromdate" },
            { "data": "_todate" },
            { "data": "_strLvType" },
            { "data": "_leavedurationtype" },
            { "data": "_leavedurationtype" },
            { "data": "_leavedurationtype" },
        ],
    "columnDefs": [{
        "targets": -1,
        "data": data,
        "defaultContent": "<button>Click!</button>"
    }]
    ,"language":
    {
        "processing": "<div class='row text-center waitIconDiv' id='LoadIconDiv'><img alt='Progress' src='~/Content/images/wait_icon.gif' width='50' height='50' id='imgProgLvRprt' /></div>"
    },
});
```

`Month` and `year` may vary.

Comment: can you show your controller action?

Comment: and have a look at this article : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1170086/Implement-Grid-with-Server-Side-Advanced-Search-us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to call the `ajax.reload()` on the datatable instance in whatever event of whatever element you want  :

```
LeaveDetailsTable.ajax.reload();
```

which will post the state of datatables with your new parameters that got added in `data` property to the controller action.

You can also take a look at [this article (Server Side Advanced Search using JQuery DataTables)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1170086/Implement-Grid-with-Server-Side-Advanced-Search-us) which explains how to send custom parameters to controller action with JQuery DataTables.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this I recommend you to use jquery `onchange` method. For example:

```
$('.input-class').on('change', function () {
    $table.fnDraw();
});
```

Here `$table` refers the name of your Datatable and `fnDraw()` is a Datatable function to refresh your table.
And obviously you need to add data from search field to the request. For this, I recommend you going through link below:

[datatables](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax)